# Inserting multiple checkbox values with a same text field value (codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox

I'm trying to put values into a MySQL table like this one:

## |---sbjct_name---|---level---|

|---------- Physics ----------|----Level 1-----|

|---------- Physics ----------|----Level 2-----|

|---------- Physics ----------|----Level 3-----|

|---------- Calculus ---------|----Level 1-----|

|---------- Calculus ---------|----Level 2-----|

(I don't know how to make table but I guess u get the idea)

Let say I'm going to put "Math" into sbjct_name column alongside with "Level 1", "Level 2", "Level 3" values into the level column.

The basic idea is from [this pict (selecting value for a same input text value)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05Vds.png).

Instead of inserting "Math" multiple times for each level,
I'm trying to make it one time submit with checkbox tag. It will be something like [this pict (with checkbox)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaTRe.png).

I don't have any idea how to make this happen (or if it possible in CI).

This is some code from my Controller,

```
public function add_subject()
{
    $data = array();

    if ($this->input->post('savebttn'))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('sbjct_name', 'Subject Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('level', 'Level', '|required|is_natural');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span class="fielderror">','</span>');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $data['reset'] = FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
           //I don't know what to do here
           //I don't know what to do here
           //I don't know what to do here
           //I don't know what to do here
        }
    }
    $data['level'] = $this->admin_model->get_checkbox_option('level', 'lvl_id', 'lvl_name');
    $data['page'] = 'createsubject';
    $this->load->view('admin/main', $data);
}
```

This is a checkbox view function in the Model,

```
public function get_checkbox_option($table, $id, $name, $selected=0)
{
    $query = $this->db->get($table);
    $select= '';
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $selected_option = ($selected == $row[$id]) ? 'selected = "selected" ':' ';
            $select .='<input type="checkbox" name="level" value="'.$row[$id].'" '.$selected_option.'>'.$row[$name].'<br>';
        }
    }
    return $select;
}
```

This is the form on the View,

```
    <form action="" method="post" id="createcategoryform">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><div class="label">Subject Name</div></td>
                    <td><div class="input">
                        <input type="text" name="sbjct_name" size="39" class="ui-corner-all input-text validate[required]">
                        <?=form_error('sbjct_name');?>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><div class="label">Level</div></td>
                    <td><div class="input-text ui-corner-all validate[required]">
                        <?=(isset($level)) ? $level: '';?>
                    </div><?=form_error('level');?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Save" name="savebttn" class="input-button ui-corner-all ui-state-default"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
```

I will be grateful if you can give any clue. :D

Comment: Can you explain what you really want? its very unclear, I can't seem to understand it.

Comment: @Dray I have editted my question.  I hope it's clearer than before. Thank you for your respond by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**first**

make your checkbox as an array so it look like this

```
$select .='<input type="checkbox" name="level[]" value="'.$row[$id].'" '.$selected_option.'>'.$row[$name].'<br>';
```

give attention to the name. yours `name="level"` and mine `name="level[]"`
, then you can grab all level as one variable

**second**

make your controller like this

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $data['reset'] = FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
          // make array container for input batch
          $insertData = array();
          if(!empty($this->input->post('level'))) {
              foreach($this->input->post('level') as $level) {
                    $tempArray = array(
                      'sbjct_name' => $this->input->post('sbjct_name'),
                      'level' => $level
                    );

                    array_push($insertData, $tempArray);
              }

              // it's better to put this in model
              // but for example purpose I put it there
              $this->db->insert_batch('table', $insertData);

              //do what you want to do here
          }
        }
```

hope you get the point @nasamikhail

Comment: I got your idea about inserting array of array. I tried it. It didn't generate any error but it didn't work yet though. 
I think I need to make a view adjustment in my code.
This is very useful, thanks!

Comment: I know why it didn't work the first time. I recklessly copied your code. There is this tiny thing @Khaer Ansori. You forgot to put the keyword "array" to define the $tempArray variable. Aside of that, your code works perfectly fine!

The code should be like this:
$tempArray = array(.....);

I have edited your answer so people can see the right answer and learn from it. Thanks again, man!